# mysql find all versions of a book except the highest version

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a sql table of the following form:

```
id | bookid | version
1|B1|1
2|B2|1
3|B1|2
4|B1|3
5|B1|4
6|B2|2
7|B3|1
```

Where `id` is the primary key. I want to find out all the `id`s for every book except the latest version. The version column is of type `bigint`.

`B3` should be ignored from the result because it has only 1 version.

So basically my resultant table should be:

```
1|B1|1
2|B2|1
3|B1|2
4|B1|3
```

My idea:

```
select id from titles where id not in (
select id, bookid, max(version) from titles group by bookid)
```

Obviously the above query doesn't work. I need to get only id in my inner query, but I'm not able to figure out how to groupby and find max as well. The above query also doesn't filter the case like B3 which has only 1 version. Maybe the way to tackle that is first find all ids which have only 1 version and have the outer query take care of ignoring such ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exists logic provides one concise way to formulate your query:

```
SELECT id, bookid, version
FROM titles t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM titles t2
              WHERE t2.bookid = t1.bookid AND t2.version > t1.version);
```

Read in plain English, the above query says to return every record such that we can find some *other* record for the same book having a higher version number.  Note that this logic therefore *excludes* the record for each book with the highest version.

Comment: Wow so simple and elegant!! Thanks!! Because of the way the inner query is written it will ensure in my example B3 is not there in the result as it can't find a version higher than itself. Is that correct?

Comment: @user1692342 Correct, and you have read the above query right.